# jquery button event on multiple buttons with the same class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having trouble with a button.

With php I am setting the name of the button, so it is not known beforehand what the name of the button is. The button however have a class, but there are multiple buttons. When I click on one of the buttons, all buttons fire their event because they all have the same class.

is there a way that I can make it that only one button fire the event?
Here is my code:

```
    <button class="delad" name="<?php print $user; ?>">Delete this ad? </button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    count = 0;
    if(count == 0)
    $(".delad").click(function(e)
    {
        e.stopPropagation() 
        v1 =$(this).attr('name');
        sum = {'v1': v1};
        sum = JSON.stringify(sum);

        $.ajax(
                {
                    url: 'del_ad.php',
                     data: 'json='+ sum,
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                        alert(data)
                    }
                });
                count += 1;

    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: You want to press the button only once?

Comment: can you tell how many time you get same button..

Comment: add another class or id to the button you want to use as a trigger for the event, if you can't do this the other option would be to target the correct button using it's parent's selector $('.btn-container>.delad')... on the other hand if you're using the name to include data you could perhaps use a data attribute instead like data-user and extract it using $(this).data('user')

Comment: Hey, its not like all event will be fired on element click. JQuery just attach the event listener to all element with that particular class. However event is fired for only that element which is clicked. You may put alert(v1)..it would be invoked only once per click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<button id="dino" class="delad" name="<?php print $user; ?>">Delete this ad? </button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
count = 0;
if(count == 0)
$("#dino").click(function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation() 
    v1 =$(this).attr('name');
    sum = {'v1': v1};
    sum = JSON.stringify(sum);

    $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'del_ad.php',
                 data: 'json='+ sum,
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    alert(data)
                }
            });
            count += 1;

});
```

});

Comment: I am unable to use id="dino" as there are multiple buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can determine which button that was clicked by using 'this', with 'this' you can access the attribute of the html object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[class='my_class']").click(function(){ //get all button with the class of 'myclass'
        alert($(this).attr('name')); //'this' determines which button was clicked
        //ajax call
    });
});
```

Please see this example :)
http://jsfiddle.net/silkherb/o7qpehwg/2/

Comment: With this code it alert me with all the buttons of this class, so yes it does what I want, except that it fires the event for all the buttons with that class.

Comment: Hey man, so the problem is, that you want any of the buttons to get all the names on the 'buttons with the same class'? or i am wrong? i created new example with a new 'button3'  http://jsfiddle.net/silkherb/f855euvp/1/

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this would be practical or not but that would depend on how many buttons you have.

As you can see in the code below you would test to see which button was clicked and then apply the function approriate to it.

I think this will work for you going by the information you gave even though i am assuming the location of the button on the page will be appropriate to a certain function regardless of the name it has.

```
$(".delad").on("click", function(){
    var btnName = $(this).attr("name");
    if($(btnName) == <?php echo $nameOfButton1;?>){

        //do something thats specific 
        //to the button with this name

    }else if($(btnName) == <?php echo $nameOfButton2;?>){

        //do something thats specific 
        //to the button with this name

    }else if($(btnName) == <?php echo $nameOfButton3;?>){

        //do something thats specific 
        //to the button with this name
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It would if I knew how many buttons there were, but that's my problem, it is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Well this has happened to me and the problem was the script was called multiple times (in a loop)!

Just putting this out there just in case someone has the same problem.